# script to watch new files in a folder and when found, based on filename call different scripts

Tags: unix

I am trying to design a file watcher solution in which I need to watch a particular folder for different file names everyday, once the file name is found, I need to call a script specific to the file name.

Example:

```
Watch Folder -
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

call script.sh abc file1
call script.sh abc file2
call script.sh abc file3
```

I tried to make use of the inotifywait but have not been able to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
sftp_home=/app/public/ent_sftp
script=/app/public/bin
curr_date=$(TZ=":US/Eastern" date '+%Y%m%d')

inotifywait -m $sftp_home -e create -e moved_to |
while read path action file; do
echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
if [ "$file" = "file1${curr_date}*.txt" ]; then
echo "file1${curr_date}*.txt was found and process will be initiated"
cd $script
./script.sh file1
elif [ "$file" = "file2${curr_date}*.txt" ]; then
echo "file2${curr_date}*.txtwas found today and process will be initiated"
cd $script
./script.sh file2
fi
done
```

Thanks,
Kavin

Comment: `if [ "$file" = "file1${curr_date}*.txt" ]` will attempt to match the literal string and will not do any sort of glob expansion.  Do your names contain a literal `*` ?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Hi thanks for replying back. Ah got it,  No they don't. They actually have a random generated number in the end, file_06_07_2021_021.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do glob expansions in the match, you can do that with a case statement:

```
unset arg
case $file in
file1${curr_date}*.txt)
        arg=file1
        ;;
file2${curr_date}*.txt)
        arg=file2
        ;;
*)
        echo No file found >&2
        ;;
esac
if test -n "$arg"; then
        echo "${arg}${curr_date}*.txt was found and process will be initiated"
        cd $script
        ./script.sh "$arg"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks much , this works like a charm! really appreciate the help. I actually had to pass two arguments to the script for each case which would make the final script call like  ./script.sh "$arg1" "$arg2" . How do I achieve  this with this script ?

Comment: Assign the arguments in each section of the case.  You can have arbitrarily many commands between `)` and `;;` in each section.

Comment: Thanks again! Appreciate it.